# Most frequent element in NumPy ND array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to find and print the most common number in a matrix, using numpy if possible.

This list was given (made it a matrix using numpy.matrix(list)):

```
import numpy as np
list = [[2,4,1,6,3], [2,4,1,8,4], [6,5,4,3,2], [6,5,4,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5]]
matrix=np.matrix(list)
```

for this example i should be getting: 4
(as it is the most  common number)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: thought about flattening the matrix and running a loop counting each number between 1-9, though it's too complex and i'm sure there's a simpler solution i'm missing

Comment: Don't use `np.matrix`. It's got all sorts of weird compatibility issues, it's deprecated, and people often find that they want the exact opposite of the behavior they asked for by using it.

Comment: Take a look at `numpy.unique`. You can return counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> LoL = [[2,4,1,6,3], [2,4,1,8,4], [6,5,4,3,2], [6,5,4,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5]]
>>> matrix=np.array(LoL)
>>> matrix
[[2 4 1 6 3]
 [2 4 1 8 4]
 [6 5 4 3 2]
 [6 5 4 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4 5]]
```

You can do:

```
>>> np.argmax(np.bincount(matrix.flat))
4
```

Or,

```
u, c = np.unique(your_lst, return_counts=True)
u[c.argmax()]
# 4
```

---

If you wanted to do this without numpy or any import to count the most frequent entry in a list of lists, you can use a dictionary to count each element from a generator that is flattening your list of lists:

```
cnts={}
for e in (x for sl in LoL for x in sl):
    cnts[e]=cnts.get(e, 0)+1
```

Then sort by most frequent:

```
>>> sorted(cnts.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
[(4, 7), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (8, 1)]
```

Or, just use `max` if you only want the largest:

```
>>> max(cnts.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])
```

Comment: wow! worked great, though instead of np.array I used np.matrix and it still worked. so i will ask you as i asked the others... why shouldnt i use it?
(tried to upvote though i'm still new)

Comment: `np.matrix` is being deprecated and, in this case, `np.array` produces the matrix you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an intermediate matrix. You can directly flatten your list to get a single list and use [bincount](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). It returns a list where the frequency of each number is given at the index position which corresponds to the number. That's why you use `argmax` to get the corresponding index

```
import numpy as np
listt = [[2,4,1,6,3], [2,4,1,8,4], [6,5,4,3,2], [6,5,4,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5]]
flat = [i for j in listt for i in j]
counts = np.bincount(flat)
print (np.argmax(counts))
# 4
```

Comment: `sum(listt, [])` is one of the worst possible ways to flatten a list, and it doesn't work at all with a NumPy matrix. Also, `bincount` does not return a list.

Comment: @user2357112: The user has started by initialising a list and then later converting to numpy matrix. The conversion to NumPy matrix is not needed here. I replaced `sum` part with a list comprehension. And what is this argument about bincount not returning alist? What is its relevance to `sum`?

Comment: worked great!
i'd like to understand fully: how did the sum(list,[]) flattend the matrix?
is there any way to do it without flattening?

Comment: @Omer: I removed the sum part for flattening a list and replaced it by list comprehension as some user didn't like it for being inefficient. It basically takes all the `[]` instances and sums them. If you have two lists a = [1,2,3] and b = [4,5,6] then a+b merges the two lists to give [1,2,3,4,5,6]. This is what sum(listt, []) was doing

Comment: @user2357112: I am not using it on Numpy matrix. I really don't understand your downvote apart from the `sum` argument being inefficient which I took care of in my edit. As coldspeed also said, numpy matrix was not needed here.

Comment: thank you very much!! tried to upvote but still new so it doesnt count yet.
i agree using a matrix is pretty useless here, though it is what I was requested so...

Comment: @Omer: You are welcome. Glad you find the answer helpful